# Application Church-Turing thesis

Tags: logic, computability, recursive-algorithms

I would like to give examples of problems which are solvable with an algorithm, for example the function $f$ which maps the tuple $(n,m)$ to the greatest common divisor. This map is recursive. I would do it in the following way: 1st step: If $m$ equals $0$, then $\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)=n$. 2nd step: otherwise $\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)=gcd(m,n \mod m)$.

What about the set of polynomials in one variable with integer coefficients? I want to argue that the subset of the polynomials which have an integer root is recursive.

Moreover, why is the addition and multiplication of rational numbers a recursive function? What about the exponentiation of two rational numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about the exponentiation of two rational numbers?

I assume you mean positive rational numbers with a rational exponent.

As a formal symbol $q^r$ with related rules of calculation, it all boils down to prime factorization and rules for integer exponentiation, which are recursive in any reasonable discrete representation.   However, if you mean calculation of real numbers equal to the exponentiated rationals, you will need infinite series (or more complicated things) to define a recursive sequence of rational approximations, and basic operations on the real number representation (like checking which of two expressions with rational exponentials is larger) are either not recursive or it can be difficult to prove correctness or termination of the algorithms.

The other questions are simpler. Test for an integer root of a polynomial with integer coefficients can be done by searching through divisors of the first and last coefficients, which reduces the problem to integer factorization.  Addition and multiplication are done by polynomial formulas, so if you know integer addition and multiplication are recursive, this is enough to get the recursiveness of rational fractions.

Comment: By "series" do you mean "sequence"?

Comment: I mean forming a sequence of approximations by taking the sum of the first several terms of an infinite series, such as the binomial series for calculation of rational exponents.  @QuinnCulver

Comment: I do not see right now, what $q^r$ has to do with prime factorization when both values are rational, may you could explain me this a little bit more in detail?

Comment: I don't know if you strictly need prime factorization, but you would never need more than that.  Any product of positive rational numbers raised to rational powers is equivalent to a finite set of rational exponents on the primes that appear in the numerator or denominator of the rationals involved in the product.

Comment: A series is not necessary. Given rationals $q$ and $r$,one could simply search through the rations until one is found that is to desired precision. (I'll elaborate if you'd like.)

Comment: @QuinnCulver, I don't think it's so clear. If you want the real number $q^r$ exponents to be closed under product (or some other operations), or to implement infinite precision real arithmetic on a computer, or to know that the search algorithm terminates for every desired precision, or to work in a context where there is a definite meaning to the existence and termination requirements (on the algorithm) in the definition of recursive --- then some convergence proof is needed. The two standard routes are the binomial theorem and iterations like Newton's method.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, and maybe we're talking past eachother, but all I'm saying is that to find a rational within $\epsilon$ of, say, $2^{1/2}$, all you have to do is search for a rational $r$ such that $r^2$ is within $\delta(\epsilon)$ of $2$ (where $\delta$ is the modulus of continuity function for $x^{1/2}$, which is computable). I don't see why you're mentioning a proof of convergence.

Comment: Recursive requires that the algorithm terminates on all inputs.  If you allow algorithms without termination proofs, and a broad enough set of operations to produce many transcendental numbers, then these number notations will lack closure properties (examples: for particular positive rationals, is a^b^c recursive? Is its sum with d^e^f recursive?).  If you require proofs, then they will include some computable bound on convergence of an algorithm to calculate rational approximations, and for $q^r$ this is done with the series/sequence methods listed in the previous comment.  @QuinnCulver

Comment: The algorithm I described clearly terminates. Proof: the rationals are dense. The fact is that the (field of) computable numbers is closed under all the usual operations, because they're (uniformly) computable. The proofs of convergence are all easy and require no series. Transcendentalism of numbers is irrelevant, since some are computable and some aren't.

Comment: "rationals are dense" does not show that a real square root of 2 exists.  That is the step that requires some machinery of analysis (series, sequences, estimates, Newton's method, etc).  Computable numbers' closure under the operations is representation dependent, for example, it is false if a real number is defined by a computable sequence of bits representing its binary digits.  Apart from this, the point was that recursion theory tends to hedge on what "exists" and "terminates" mean in the definition of computable and in what way they are given as part a recursive object. @QuinnCulver

Comment: I was not trying to prove that the real square root of 2 exists, but just that the algorithm outputs a sequence that converges to it.